# Ubuntu - Apt-get Install failure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install package XScreensaver. This is on a HP T410 Thin client and I am using XTerminal; `lsb_release -a` (OS version) returns: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS - Lucid.

Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` returns error message: "Unable to execute new pre-installation script: no such file or directory" for one of the packages, dash_0.5.8-2.4_armel.deb.

and

Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` returns error message: "Couldn't configure pre-depend fuse for ntfs-3g, probably a dependency cycle".

I have read that opening the problem package in text editor can reveal if there are any prerequisite programs required, but I can only see "debian-binary" (which returns a package not found when trying to install, but it would error out anyway) and control.tar.gz which I assume is the file name. Any idea on how I can correct the above? This is the standard configuration for the thin client so there hasn't been any changes to the build to cause this.

I have tried; installing each dependency line manually (this just keeps shoving more dependencies at me- I haven't managed to install 1 yet), using dpkg to remove the package (it redownloads when I use app-upgrade again), using the '-f' switch to force the dependency download but this still just shows: 'depends: .... but it is not going to be installed' for each line.

Any ideas/alternatives greatly appreciated. I just want a screensaver for the thin client... (it uses RDP, so we can't set a screensaver on server side as when the RDP session 'locks' - it just shows the RDP lock screen, not the server screensaver).

Comment: Support for 10.04 ended in 2015. You won't be able to install any software that depends on online repositories because they no longer exist. Please upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.. I had assumed that because it was picking the package up that it was available for me to download but that's just what sources.list is returning. I have found http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/multiverse/ - do you know if I can still link this up?  - Post your reply as answer and I will mark as answered for you.

Comment: I cannot recommend using an End if Life release, especially one missing security updates for 4 years already.

Comment: I agree, I will try a newer OS on the thin client. Thanks for you help. As mentioned above feel free to add as answer and I will mark it as complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 reached End of Life in 2015.

Software in online repositories is no longer available because the repositories are no longer available, having been moved.

Unsupported old releases shouldn't be used if connected to the internet due to security concerns. Ubuntu 10.04 hasn't received any security updates since 2015.